# Return all nodes from XML file, even when they are empty

Tags: xml, vba, msxml

I have an XML file retrieved via WSDL in Access 2010 via VBA. The XML file is sitting in this variable

```
Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument60
```

The part of the XML I'm interested in looks like the below and basically just reiterates itself for every `UserBean`. A `UserBean` is basically a user account in a system.

```
<UserBean xsi:type="ns1:UserBean">  
    <primaryKey xsi:type="xsd:string">49084</primaryKey>  
    <updateIndex xsi:type="xsd:int">14</updateIndex>  
    <deleted xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</deleted>  
    <loginID xsi:type="xsd:string">61420313556</loginID>  
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Andrew Mills</name>    
    <teams xsi:type="soapenc:Array" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]">  
        <string xsi:type="xsd:string">Maintenance</string>  
    </teams>  
    <timezone xsi:type="xsd:string">Australia/Brisbane</timezone>  
    <userTypePK xsi:type="xsd:string">3776</userTypePK>  
    <description xsi:type="xsd:string"/>  
    <emailAddress xsi:type="xsd:string"/>  
    <phoneNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>  
    <faxNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>  
    <pagerNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>  
    <mobileNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">61420313556</mobileNumber>  
    <securityQuestion xsi:type="xsd:string">__INVALID</securityQuestion>  
    <securityAnswer xsi:type="xsd:string"/>  
    <synchronisation xsi:type="soapenc:Array" soapenc:arrayType="ns2:SynchronisationBean[0]" xmlns:ns2="http://soap2.nads.econz.co.nz"/>  
</UserBean>
```

The problem is that not every field is mandatory to be filled in.
Therefore some nodes have no data
Using the MSXML2 library in VBA only returns nodes if there is actually text in it.
Therefore the code below will return a variable amount of nodes depending on what each userbean contains.  For example some users dont have a mobileNumber populated.

```
Set nodes xmlDoc.selectNodes("//UserBean")
For Each node in nodes  
    debug.print node.text  
next node
```

The above code returns a long string that has all of the values of all of the child nodes in it (with respect to the `Userbean` node), but only the ones that have text.  I'm trying to get this into a table in Access and if some of the nodes are missing some of the time, I've got no way of tracking it... or do I?

How do I return ALL nodes whether they are populated or not
OR
How do I identify the name of the node that has the text so I know where to put the value into the table in Access?

***UPDATE***
Further to the below comments, what i'm after is a list of Userbeans, which are in themselves a list...so in fact i'm after a list of lists...so with that in mind I tried the below but it failed at the first `For Each` loop. Obviously that type of loop can't handle using lists as a counter for another list. Is there a way around this?

```
Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim userbeans As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim userbean As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

Set userbeans = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//UserBean")
For Each userbean In userbeans '**Type mismatch error here**
    For Each node In userbean
          Debug.Print node.nodeName & ":" & node.Text
    Next node
Next userbean
```

Comment: Maybe: `debug.print node.nodename & "=" & node.text`

Comment: That's close @Tim Williams. The result of your code is  `UserBean=4908414false614203Andrew....etc`  so the fields aren't getting broken up. The `UserBean` is really a list of nodes, but here its being treated as one node.

Comment: If at all possible, spin up an SQL server engine -- it has FAR better XML capacities than Access.  FWIW.

Comment: @DougM - sorry, what do you mean by 'spin up an SQL server engine'? Happy to do this in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: Microsoft's SQL Server.  The Express version includes the full syntax, and can easily serve as the back-end to a single desktop application.  And if it's a multi-user access application, you really should migrate to a central network box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what i'm after is a list of Userbeans, which are in themselves a list

You need to think in terms of "nodes", not "lists."  `selectNodes` returns a pointer to a set of nodes, but when you iterate through it you wind up with an IXMLDOMNode, not a Node List.  You can only get a nodeList by calling a method, such as selectNodes.

You can to call selectNodes *again*, or just use the IXMLDOMNode's  `childNodes` property, [Documented at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757053.aspx)

```
Dim userBeanList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim userbean As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim beanChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Set userBeanList = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//UserBean")
For Each userBean In userBeanList 
    For Each beanChild In userBean.childNodes
          Debug.Print beanChild.nodeName & ":" & beanChildText
    Next beanChild
Next userBean
```

Note that with a proper XPath Query, you can just select a list of nodes that meet your criteria.  And since this is VBA, you can skip the explicit declarations unless you're going to take advantage of the intellisense.

```
dim badNodes, badNode
set badNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//UserBean/*[not(text())]")
if badNodes.length < 1 then
  debug.Print "All good!"
else
  debug.Print "following nodes are empty:"
  For Each badNode in badNodes
    debug.print " - " & badNode.name
  next badNode
endif
```

Comment: tried to edit your post as `badNode.name` should be `badNode.nodeName` but its less than the required amount of characters to enforce an edit.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and both work great. Thanks so much, ive learnt a lot from both of your approaches. Once I get the data into a table Ill post my final solution for all to share. Thanks again.